# git compiling: Documentation/git-add.xml does not validate

Tags: git, compiler-construction, gnu

When compiling git I have these errors:

```
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/xxx/git-master'
    XMLTO git-add.1
xmlto: /home/xxx/git-master/Documentation/git-add.xml does not validate (status 3)
xmlto: Fix document syntax or use --skip-validation option
I/O error : Attempt to load network entity http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.5/docbookx.dtd
/home/xxx/git-master/Documentation/git-add.xml:2: warning: failed to load external entity "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.5/docbookx.dtd"
D DocBook XML V4.5//EN" "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.5/docbookx.dtd"
I/O error : Attempt to load network entity http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.5/docbookx.dtd
warning: failed to load external entity "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.5/docbookx.dtd"
validity error : Could not load the external subset "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.5/docbookx.dtd"
Document /home/xxx/git-master/Documentation/git-add.xml does not validate
make[1]: *** [git-add.1] Error 13
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/xxx/git-master/Documentation'
make: *** [doc] Error 2
```

What is the main problem?

Answer (score 7):

Late to the party, but on cygwin the package you need for this to validate is `docbook-xml45` (as implied by the DTD URI, docbook/xml/4.5/docbookx.dtd)

Answer (score 7):

On OSX (Mountain Lion) I had to do this:

```
brew install asciidoc
brew install xmlto
brew install docbook   

# then (as prompted by brew...)
#
# If you intend to process AsciiDoc files through an XML stage
# (such as a2x for manpage generation) you need to add something
# like:
#
export XML_CATALOG_FILES=/usr/local/etc/xml/catalog
#
# to your shell rc file so that xmllint can find AsciiDoc's
# catalog files.

brew install docbook-xsl
```

(Thanks to Nathan for providing the necessary hints).
#6chars

Comment: The answerer provides the helpful variable assignment (`export XML_CATALOG_FILES...`) in the commented output. Be sure run that before proceeding with your git make command!

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be something of a reoccurring issue for git.  In hunting down the solution (today), I ran across it in several forums.  (Linux, Cygwin, Mac OS).  The problem is always the same:  lack of a good docbook catalog.  Unfortunately, installing the appropriate catalog is HIGHLY dependent on your installation, and there is more than one way to lack a good catalog.

1. A bad catalog was released a few years ago.  Uninstall & install the update.
2. The package that built the catalog failed part way.  Remove & reinstall the package.
3. The package that installs the catalog has not been installed, and the package tools haven't taken care of you.

Option 3 is where I was.  I have brew installed, so 
    sudo brew install docbook
    sudo docbook-register
Took care of this problem for me.

Alternatively, there is a separate download of just the docs available.

Answer (score 2):

jonseymour answer helped me in Mac OS X El Capitan

to export XML_CATALOG_FILES=/usr/local/etc/xml/catalog I do this

```
sudo vim ~/.bash_profile

(in an empty line insert)
export XML_CATALOG_FILES=/usr/local/etc/xml/catalog

save & exit

. ~/.bash_profile
```

solved

Answer (score 2):

Note: you might find this error again in more recent (2019, seven years later) build, because Git is starting to use DocBook 5 (instead of DocBook 4.5), as Asciidoctor 2.0
no longer works with the older one.
Git 2.24 (Q4 2019) clarifies the situation.

See [commit f6461b8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f6461b82b932013f170acf357c4dd3468c923f73) (15 Sep 2019) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit faf5576](https://github.com/git/git/commit/faf5576a8d749c7c46fafd0c62da47ec078e1486), 06 Oct 2019)</sup>

> ### Documentation: fix build with Asciidoctor 2
>
> Our documentation toolchain has traditionally been built around DocBook 4.5.
>   This version of DocBook is the last DTD-based version of DocBook.
>   In 2009, DocBook 5 was introduced using namespaces and its syntax is expressed in RELAX NG, which is more expressive and allows a wider variety of syntax forms.
>
> Asciidoctor, one of the alternatives for building our documentation, moved support for DocBook 4.5 out of core in its recent 2.0 release and now only supports DocBook 5 in the main release.
>   The DocBoook 4.5 converter is still available as a separate component, but this is not
>   available in most distro packages.
>   This would not be a problem but for the fact that we use xmlto, which is still stuck in the DocBook 4.5 era.
>
> `xmlto` performs DTD validation as part of the build process.
>   This is not problematic for DocBook 4.5, which has a valid DTD, but it clearly
>   cannot work for DocBook 5, since no DTD can adequately express its full
>   syntax.
>   In addition, even if `xmlto` did support `RELAX NG` validation, that wouldn't be sufficient because it uses the libxml2-based `xmllint` to do so, which has known problems with validating interleaves in `RELAX NG`.
>
> Fortunately, there's an easy way forward: ask Asciidoctor to use its DocBook 5 backend and tell `xmlto` to skip validation.
>   Asciidoctor has supported DocBook 5 since v0.1.4 in 2013 and xmlto has supported
>   skipping validation for probably longer than that.
>
> We also need to teach `xmlto` how to use the namespaced DocBook XSLT stylesheets instead of the non-namespaced ones it usually uses.
>   Normally these stylesheets are interchangeable, but the non-namespaced ones have a bug that causes them not to strip whitespace automatically from certain elements when namespaces are in use.
>   This results in additional whitespace at the beginning of list elements, which is
>   jarring and unsightly.
>
> We can do this by passing a custom stylesheet with the `-x` option that
>   simply imports the namespaced stylesheets via a URL.
>   Any system with support for XML catalogs will automatically look this URL up and
>   reference a local copy instead without us having to know where this
>   local copy is located.  We know that anyone using `xmlto` will already
>   have catalogs set up properly since the DocBook 4.5 DTD used during
>   validation is also looked up via catalogs.
>   All major Linux distributions distribute the necessary stylesheets and have built-in
>   catalog support, and Homebrew does as well, albeit with a requirement to
>   set an environment variable to enable catalog support.
>
> On the off chance that someone lacks support for catalogs, it is possible for `xmlto` (via `xmllint`) to download the stylesheets from the URLs in question, although this will likely perform poorly enough to attract attention.
>   People still have the option of using the prebuilt documentation that we ship, so happily this should not be an impediment.
>
> Finally, we need to filter out some messages from other stylesheets that occur when invoking dblatex in the CI job.
>   This tool strips namespaces much like the unnamespaced DocBook stylesheets and prints similar messages.
>   If we permit these messages to be printed to standard error,
>   our documentation CI job will fail because we check standard error for
>   unexpected output.
>   Due to `dblatex`'s reliance on Python 2, we may need to revisit its use in the future, in which case this problem may go away, but this can be delayed until a future patch.
>
> The final message we filter is due to `libxslt` on modern Debian and
>   Ubuntu.
>   The patch which they use to implement reproducible ID generation also prints messages about the ID generation.
>   While this doesn't affect our current CI images since they use Ubuntu 16.04 which
>   lacks this patch, if we upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 or a modern Debian,
>   these messages will appear and, like the above messages, cause a CI failure.